# replace control character ascii into page

Tags: post-content, characters

I observe that a copy-paste containing the control character '^L' (ie FF) causes an error with 'vimrepress'.

Wordpress publishes the page but vimpress cannot load it.
I would like to replace this '^L' character with a space in one and, if possible, several pages either with "adminer", or with a plugin, or from the editor.

Any ideas ?

NB: WP 5.4.1; mysql 5.7.28; PHP 5.6.39

Answer (score 0):

first workaround:

1. Edit the page under wordpress classic editor
   and copy (ctrl-C) the whole to the clipboard.
2. Open the vim editor
3. Copy (ctrl-V) the clipboard to the vim window
4. Replace all control characters with a space
      :%s/[^@-^M]/ /g (ie ctrl-V ctrl- @ and ctrl-V ctrl-M)
5. Overwrite the page content in wordpress with the new vim content via the clipboard